# Avoid repeating SQL fragment in query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query (pseudo code)

```
SELECT 
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(
                         (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()) <---long query
                         ), 0) = 0 THEN 'found'
            ELSE 
              SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())     <--- repeated long query
        END
```

The problem is that the `SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())` which in reality is very long query.

Is there any workaround for this "long expression" not to appear twice in the query ?

p.s.

I have a solution of calculating `SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())` into an outside  variable... but I'm trying to figure out if there's an inline solution.

Comment: Have heard about stored procedures and functions?

Comment: I think you should post code for your long query showing how you are restricting data to one row. The query above will fail because it will return multiple rows.

Comment: @rs it wont fail... it return 1 value foreach row.

Comment: I would probably use `cross apply` if your query always return one row and `outer apply` if it returns zero or one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular pattern of usage of a subquery in your example could be re-written like this:

```
…
c = COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF((subquery), 0) AS varchar(10)), 'found')
…
```

As Mikael Eriksson has correctly pointed out in his comment, you may need to use `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE` here, because one of the arguments contains a subquery and `ISNULL` may (or, in fact, will) be more efficient in this case, as you can see elaborated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668140/isnull-and-coalesce-proper-usage/10669660#10669660).

so here is the fixed ver :

```
…
c = ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF((subquery), 0) AS varchar(10)), 'found')
…
```

Note, though, that if you end up switching to `ISNULL`, you should pay attention to the length of the second string (`'found'`) if you ever decide to change it too. The thing is, `ISNULL` will (attempt to) cast the second argument to the exact type of the first argument, including the maximum length of the string specified (`10` in this case). If your second argument becomes something like `'NULL or zero is found'` instead of just `'found'`, `ISNULL` will not return the entire string but only the first 10 characters instead (`'NULL or ze'`). So you'll need to remember to change the type of the first argument as well (to `varchar(20)`, for instance).

Comment: we both knew exactly what ive been searching .

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668140/isnull-and-coalesce-proper-usage/10669660#10669660) answer is applicable here. Probably should use isnull instead of coalesce to avoid executing the sub query twice.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Please have a look at my update, just so you were aware of an option (probably, a better one) here.

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of options available:

- User-defined function (UDF)
- Views
- Common Table Expression (CTE)
- CROSS/OUTER APPLY

Depending on how the data is being processed will determine which is the best fit.  Your question doesn't provide enough detail to definitively offer a suggestion, but these are worth looking at.

Be careful with using UDF as they can quickly hinder performance.  My person rule of thumb is to write a UDF for simple data transformations or mathematical calculation. I try to avoid doing complicated set-based operations in a function and will prefer a view or CTE for that.

Comment: how will cte help here ? and UDF is not an options  - as you said - bad performance. the only option is view... but i was hoping for some other idea. i guess view is the only option left...( as i was thinking)

Comment: What I use are CTE's also, the optimizer can (usually) work with them fine, just double check the plan before releasing it for production.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL([l], 0) = 0 THEN 'found'
            ELSE [l]
        END
from tbl
cross apply (
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()) as [l]
) as [x]
```

Also, if your original query is representative of what you've actually got (i.e. returning one value if the "long expression" returns null), consider using `COALESCE` instead of a case statement. Or just use `ISNULL([l], 'found')`

Answer (score -1):

Example using CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(MONTH(GETDATE()),0) = 0 
    THEN 'FOUND' ELSE  ISNULL(MONTH(GETDATE()),0) END Col1
),
SELECT a = 1,b = 2, C = col1
FROM Table1, CTE
```

if you have any keys, that can be used to join

```
SELECT a = 1,b = 2, C = CASE WHEN ISNULL(v.col1,0) = 0 THEN 'Found' ELSE v.col1 END
        FROM Table1 a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(MONTH(DateCol),0) Col1 FROM TABLEName b
                a.id = b.id) v
```

Comment: did you read my problem ? ( MONTH(GETDATE()) is still calculated twice here)

Comment: do you have any id or unique key that you use in your subquery to get month?

Comment: what if GetDate() is a date Column in my Table? how will i "send" it to the CTE ?

Comment: IMHO it is very bad performance- since the `from x,x` the cartessian multiplation is not neccesary and it_ gives me a lot of unwanted combinations...._

Comment: yes, for same reason i asked you if there are any keys that you use to join on, if yes then we can do this differently.

Comment: it wasnt me. i just came home. checking your solution