# IsNULL and Coalesce proper usage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

As we have two options to intercept the null values coming from database...

> 1. ISNull
> 2. Coalesce

Following are the ways to write the query for the above two functions...

`Select IsNull(Columnname, '') As validColumnValue From TableName`

`Select Coleasce(Columnname, '') As validColumnValue From TableName`

Query - Which should be prefered in which situation and why?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic832742-392-1.aspx

Comment: I just wrote about this recently. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 5):

This has been hashed and re-hashed. In addition to [the tip I pointed out in the comment](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and the links and explanation @xQbert posted above, by request here is an explanation of COALESCE vs. ISNULL using a subquery. Let's consider these two queries, which in terms of results are identical:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT TOP (1) name FROM sys.objects), N'foo');

SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) name FROM sys.objects), N'foo');
```

(Comments about using TOP without ORDER BY to /dev/null/ thanks.)

In the COALESCE case, the logic actually gets expanded to something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP (1) ...) IS NULL
    THEN (SELECT TOP (1) ...)
    ELSE N'foo'
END
```

With ISNULL, this does not happen. There is an internal optimization that seems to ensure that the subquery is only evaluated once. I don't know if anyone outside of Microsoft is privy to exactly how this optimization works, but you can this if you compare the plans. Here is the plan for the COALESCE version:

[image]

And here is the plan for the ISNULL version - notice how much simpler it is (and that the scan only happens once):

[image]

In the COALESCE case the scan happens twice. Meaning the subquery is evaluated twice, even if it doesn't yield any results. If you add a WHERE clause such that the subquery yields 0 rows, you'll see similar disparity - the plan shapes might change, but you'll still see a double seek+lookup or scan for the COALESCE case. Here is a slight different example:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT TOP (1) name FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE name = N'no way this exists'), N'foo');

SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) name FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE name = N'no way this exists'), N'foo');
```

The plan for the COALESCE version this time - again you can see the whole branch that represents the subquery repeated verbatim:

[image]

And again a much simpler plan, doing roughly half the work, using ISNULL:

[image]

You can also see this question over on dba.se for some more discussion:

- [Performance difference for COALESCE versus ISNULL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4274/1186)

My suggestion is this (and you can see my reasons why in the tip and the above question): trust but verify. I always use COALESCE (because it is ANSI standard, supports more than two arguments, and doesn't do quite as wonky things with data type precedence) *unless* I know I am using a subquery as one of the expressions (which I don't recall ever doing outside of theoretical work like this) or I am experiencing a real performance issue and just want to compare to see if COALESCE vs. ISNULL has any substantial performance difference (which outside of the subquery case, I have yet to find). Since I am almost always using COALESCE with arguments of like data types, I rarely have to do any testing other than looking back at what I've said about it in the past (I was also the author of [the aspfaq article that xQbert pointed out](http://web.archive.org/web/20080509083352/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html), 7 years ago).

Comment: +1 Face it, you just like the discussion around coalesce and isnull! but in all seriousness, Some seriously indepth stuff here.

Comment: @AaronBertrand in the first 2 pictures , the first is :  (2*49.9) and  second is (1*99.8)...... so is there any difference ? what does it matter if i go 100 feet or go 50 +50 ? please explain.... :) (im lousy reading executions plans...)

Comment: @Royi Those are the percentages. If you go 200 feet, each 100 feet is 50% of your trip. If you only go 100 feet, that's 100% of your trip. Do you think you went the same distance because the percentages add up to 100 in both cases?

Comment: @AaronBertrand do you have a good article for right reading these Execution plans ?  (only if you quickly have...) thanks.

Comment: Grant Fritchey has a great free e-book. Sorry I'm on a phone, you'll have to search.

Comment: @AaronBertrand found it. http://downloads.sqlservercentral.com/Books/dissecting_complete.pdf?utm_source=ssc&utm_medium=weblink&utm_content=Grant&utm_campaign=sqltoolbelt thanks a lot.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need to verify the above cases using IsNULL in SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

***begin humor***:  The 1st, the 2nd will never work it's spelled wrong :D ***END humor***

---Cleaned up response---

**Features of isNull(value1,value2)**

- Only supports 1 valuation, if the first is null, the 2nd will be used, so if its null too you get null back!
- is non-ANSI standard.  Meaning if database portability is an issue, don't use this one
- isnull(value1,value2) will return the datatype for Value1
- will return the datatype for the selected value and fail when implicit conversions can't occur

**Features of Coalesce(Value1, Value2, value3, value...)**

- Supports multiple valuations of Null; basically will pull in the first non-null value from the list.  if all values are null in list, null is returned.
- is ANSI-standard meaning database portability shouldn't be an issue.
- will return the datatype for the selected value and fail if all fields in the select do not return the same datatype.

So to answer the question directly: 
It depends on the situation if you need to develop SQL that

- is DB independent; coalesce is more correct to use.
- allows for multiple evaluations; coalesce is more correct (of course you could just embed isnull over and over and over...) but put that under a performance microscope, and coalesce may just win. (i've not tested it)
- are you using a db engine that supports isNull? (if not use coalesce)
- how do you want type casting handled? implicitly or not.

---ORIGINAL------
is null only supports 2 evaluations

coalesce supports many more...  coalesce (columnName1, ColumnName2, ColumnName3, '')

coalesce returns datatype similar to that of case evaluation, whereas isnull returns datatype of first in list.  (which I found interesting!)

As to when to use which.  you'd have to investigate by looking at execution plan of both on SQL 2008 and 2005, different versions different engines different ways to execute.

Furthermore coalesce is ansii standard, isnull is engine specific.  Thus if you want greater portability between dbengines use coalesce.

More info [here aspfaq](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html)
or [here msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx)

Comment: I need some time to carefully read your references. I will update you shortly and accept it if found useful.

Comment: In most cases execution plans will be identical. There is one exception I know of: when one of the expressions is a subquery, it will become `CASE WHEN <subquery> IS NOT NULL THEN <subquery>...` meaning the subquery will be evaluated twice. Hopefully not many people are saying `COALESCE(<subquery>, <subquery>, ...`

Comment: can you explain it in details with an answer? I actually never used the `SubQuery` concept in `Coalesce`.

Answer (score 0):

you may take this onto consideration.

1. **ISNULL** function required two parameters: the value to check and the replacement for   null values

   2.**COALESCE** function works a bit different **COALESCE** will take any number of parameters and return  the first non-**NULL** value , I prefer **COALESCE**  over **ISNULL** 'cause 
   meets **ANSI** standarts, while **ISNULL** does not.

   I hope you found the answer to your question.