# Return 0 when result is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this statement:

```
SELECT  COUNT(AccedentId) AS NumberOfAccedentInYear
            FROM         Accident
            GROUP BY DriverId, YEAR(AccedentDate)
            HAVING     (DriverId =@DriverId)<3
```

When there are rows, I get a valid count, but when there are no rows, the result is empty. I'd like the result to be 0 when there are no matching rows.

Comment: How is the result wrong when you don't have any rows? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Wrong how?  You want `0` returned?  Your `HAVING` condition makes no sense - put that into a `WHERE` clause, and `numberOfAccedentInYear` as the value to check.  And please, spell 'accident' correctly - you even have an example in the table name!

Comment: mmm I mean I need to get the status when the Count(AccedentId) return Null value or return no row which meean 0

Comment: What is the meaning of `HAVING (DriverId =@DriverId)<3`? Do you realize that you are grouping by driver and year accident took place, and that this will return more than one row if the same driver had accidents in previous years, and that there is no guarantee that you will get most recent year first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you wanted this (I'm keeping obvious syntax and spelling errors that I can't really correct without more information):

```
SELECT NumberOfAccedentInYear = ISNULL
(
  (SELECT COUNT(AccedentId)
   FROM         Accident
   GROUP BY DriverId, YEAR(AccedentDate)
   HAVING     (DriverId =@DriverId)<3))
   , 0
);
```

For anyone curious about the COALESCE vs ISNULL discussion, and why I changed my answer to use ISNULL, @kanav rightly pointed out that COALESCE is more expensive. COALESCE evaluates the subquery twice, as I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669660/61305

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Did you check the read made by `Coalesce` in `SQL Profiler`. Profiler says - `ISNull` should be used.

Comment: @Kanav yep it's a good point, this discussion has happened lately. COALESCE is a tough habit to break. This is the one case where ISNULL is better.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Did you check 119 reads in your case and just 16 in my case !!! PLease don;t mind But I just want confirmation that AM I moving in right direction ?

Comment: @Kanav yes but I corrected my answer and acknowledged that ISNULL is more appropriate. Your comment was sufficient; your answer is out of context.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I was just emphasizing to use ISNULL. This will definitely helpful in Future for other users.