# How to get value 0 if the result of sql select except statement return no records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, except

I have a problem with the SQL Except statement, in my case, I select two columns and one column can have values and the others cannot have because the count of the first SQL statement equals the count of the second SQL after the except statement.

**Result that I got :**

```
GroupId      absences

   1            3
```

**Expected result**

```
  GroupId      absences
     1             3
     2             0
```

How can I do in this case?

```sql
select
    groupId,
    (case when groupId = null then 0 else COUNT(*) end) as absence
from (
    select
        groupId,
        COUNT(*) as  absences1
    from (
        select distinct
            MONTh,
            DAY,
            e.groupId
        from employee_c c,
            holiday hl,
            employee e,
            groups,
            Get_Calendar_Date(
                DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime)) + @Month - 1, 0),
                DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime)) + @Month-1, -1)
            )
        where DATENAME(DD, Weekday) IN (
            select WorkingdayId+1
            from timetable s,
                groups ds,
                grouptime de
            where dd.groupId = ds.groupId
                and dd.groupId = de.groupId
                and s.timetableId = de.timetableId
                and de.groupId = ds.groupdId)
                and DATEPART(MM,hl.startDate) = @Month
                and c.isActive=1 
        except
       (select Month,
               Day,
               d.departmentId
        from department d,
             Get_Calendar_Date(
                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime)) + @Month - 1, 0),
                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime)) + @Month - 1, -1)
             ),
             holiday hle,
             employee_c c,
             employee e
        where datepart(MM,hle.startDate) = @Month
                and cast(Date as date) between hle.startDate and hle.endDate
                and c.isActive=1
                and d.groupId =e.groupId
                and c.employeeId=e.employeeId
                and c.isActive=1
        )
    ) sc
    group by Month,Day,groupId
) s
group by groupId
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Also, I really suggest you start to make *good* use of white space and line breaks; that SQL is very difficult to read.

Comment: It's 2021 as well! Why are you still using that 1989 implicit JOIN syntax? The ANSI-92 explicit join syntax superseded it almost 30 years ago. Finally, a subquery, in a subquery, in a subquery almost always has a "code smell" to it.

Comment: Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729460/return-0-when-result-is-empty, hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: How a well written query should look: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17cccf31c29ead5cb7ef8ebacae19baf). After formatting it, there seems be be a wealth of problems here, if I am honest.

Comment: Sorry writing SQL in question is more complicated for me, I apologize .

Comment: @Larnu, I will modify my query next time , but for now I'm searching for a solution to my problem

Comment: Clean up your query step by step. Start by replacing the ancient comma-separated joins with proper explicit joins (`INNER JOIN` , `CROSS JOIN` etc.). At the moment there seem to be loads of cross joins in your query you may not really want. Then there is `groupId = null` which I suppose shall be `groupId IS null`? There may be more such problems; I haven't examined everything. Maybe you are looking for a mere `NOT EXISTS` clause at the end, but I don't know your tables and I don't know the real task behind the query, so it's up to you to get this straight.

Comment: Don't concentrate on my query, just give me the solution for how can I replace no records result that I got from ( a select statement except another select statement )

Comment: I often spend time cleaning up formatting because the query behind it is OK, but here I would sweep it away and start again. This query has so many issues it's hard to know where to start. The answer to your question is basically that you need `groupId` to come from another table, and `left join` the rest of it to that. But I wouldn't attempt such a thing with the query like it is.